# Packing/Unpacking arguments in Dart

Tags: dart

Is there a way in Dart to pack/unpack arguments in a function (like Python for example) ?

For **packing** example, being able to declare a function like this :

```
packArguments(*listOfArguments, **mapOfArguments) {
    listOfArguments.forEach((arg) => print(arg));
    mapOfArguments.forEach((key, val) => print("$key => $val"));
}
```

And then doing this :

```
packArguments("I", "Put", "whatever", "I", "want, arg1: "A", arg2: 1);
```

Would display :

```
I
Put
whatever
I
want
arg1 => A
arg2 => 1
```

As for **unpacking**, being able to do something like that :

```
functionWithLotOfArgument(a, b, c, d, e, {aa, bb = null, cc = null}) {
  // do stuff
}
var argList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var argMap = {"aa": "haha", bb: "baby"};

functionWithLotOfArgument(*argList, **argMap);
```

Related issue https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/29087

Comment: Currently not supported.

Comment: "Currently" means it's planned ? It would really be nice to have this feature, especially when using Flutter where methods can have a lot of parameters.

Comment: I don't think it's planned, but they are working on more broader changes and something like that might be considered later. You can check the issues https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues. I guess most features one can think of were already suggested at least once ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you ! I'll check that.

Answer (score 6):

This is not currently supported, but you can very easily pack yourself, by passing a list & map:

```
void packArguments(List listOfArguments, Map mapOfArguments) {
    listOfArguments.forEach((arg) => print(arg));
    mapOfArguments.forEach((key, val) => print("$key => $val"));
}

void main() {
  packArguments(['a', 3], {'arg1': 'a', 'arg2': 5});
}
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/98ed3a3b07a2cca049cde69ca50ca269