# Calling a function with an array of parameters in Dart

Tags: function, methods, parameters, dart

I'm trying to call a function in dart with a set of parameters that is provided in an array. I want to be able to pass the parameters to the function without knowing how many parameters there will be.

Ex:

```
someFunc(var a, var b, var c) {...}
paramArray = [1,2,3];

callFunction(var func, var params) {
  //Here is a sloppy workaround to what I want the functionality to be
  switch(params.length) {
  case 0:
      func()
      break;
    case 1: 
      func(params[0])
      break;
    case 2: 
      func(params[0], params[1])
      break;
    ...
  }
}

callFunction(someFunc, paramArray);
```

Does there exist a cleaner way to do this in dart without changing the signature of someFunc?

Answer (score 4):

The [Function.apply](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.22.1/dart-core/Function/apply.html) method does precisely what you want.
You can do `Function.apply(func, params)` and it will call `func` if the parameters match (and throw if they don't).

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge. At this point, Dart doesn't support `varargs`. For now, just take an `Iterable` as a parameter instead.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question not so long ago : [Packing/Unpacking arguments in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831703/packing-unpacking-arguments-in-dart)

Currently not supported but the dart team is aware of this feature. Not their priority though.